# Better Method of Solving Certain Differential Equations than Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been told that there is a much better method to solving differential equations than with eigenvalues and eigenvectors. However, unfortunately I was not explained this method. Can anyone present methods at which, generally, are much better than taking the eigenvalue/eigenvector route? I presume this method(s) are unorthodox, thus not well known. When I say "better" I am speaking in regards to computational complexity and efficiency. When providing answer, it would be helpful to provide a solution to an DE using both eigenvalue/eigenvector method and proposed method.

Comment: Solution to linear ODE with constant coefficient matrix is givens by matrix exponential. There are much better methods to compute matrix exponential than Jordan decomposition like scaling and squaring with Pade approximation

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to learn linear algebra, assuming "better" is more rigorous you could learn how to put matrices into Jordan canonical form and exponentiate them.

Comment: when I state "better" I am meaning more efficient in time and complexity.